# Unable to create a Community Server Connector in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was using the Community Server Connector extension a couple of days ago and it didn't cause any problems at all and allowed me to host a Tomcat server to run my webapp on but today it won't let me create a new server at all. All I get back as a response is:

```
Unable to start the server: Extension backend error - rsp error - community server connector failed to start 
- cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rspreqreject')
```

I have tried deleting the extension and reinstalling it and also restarted my system but the error persists.

Comment: Note: You seem to be running into a problem that has not been reported on the GitHub repo before. Googling `site:github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-server-connector "Extension backend error - rsp error"` comes up with a single, unrelated result.

Comment: Same issue, i think the update to the extension caused this error. Rolling back the `community server connectors` extension to version `0.25.7` seems to be working.  Version greater than 0.25.7 seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by reverting the extension to version 0.25.7.

Open the extensions list > find where Community Server Connectors is listed and click the gear icon > select "Install Another Version..." > select "0.25.7" > click the blue reload button and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue, I was battling to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same "rspreqreject" Problem.
Try downgrading the "Community Server Connectors" (e.g. v.0.25.7) . I suspect there is a discrepancy in Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the Community Server Connector successfully for several months. Suddenly today (March 7th 2023) I get the exact same problem as the author.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use the latest version of Community Server Connectors extension on VS Code. I resolved the issue by configuring the java.home environment variable for Runtime Server Protocol UI extension which came default along with Community Server Connectors.

To achieve this locate the "settings.json" file.

For mac:

1. `Cmd`+`Shift`+`P`
2. search for "json"
3. Click -> Preferences: "Open User Settings (JSON)"
4. Add the following line:
   `rsp-ui.rsp.java.home`: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/path-to-your-jdk/Contents/Home`,

Replace `path-to-your-jdk` with your jdk directory (mine was `jdk-17.jdk`)